# Is it possible for MS Word document to have multiple paging groups?

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, openxml-sdk

I'm sorry, I don't know what is the proper term for it. But I want to have multiple paging group in my documents. For example, the first 3 pages have their own separate pagination. like page 1 of 3, page 2 of 3, 3 of 3. Then the next 2 pages will have their own paging - 1 of 2, 2 of 2. And so on and so forth. If yes, what is the proper term for it and how to do it using Open XML SDK? Also during merging multiple documents, how to retain these paging? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others. See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm

Comment: The question asks how to merge multiple documents retaining the page numbering. As Open XML SDK is mentioned, the question is in fact about programming.

Comment: Yes, as @AxelKemper mentioned, I'm using Open XML SDK, so it is programming related. The reason why I asked if first if it is possible using MS Office is because if by standard it possible, it means it can be done programmatically too. Programming is just basically automating something that can be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert [section breaks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-section-break-eef20fd8-e38c-4ba6-a027-e503bdf8375c).

Within a section you can either continue the page numbering from the previous section or start page numbering with a selected page number. See menu `Layout`.

Comment: But how to do it using the Open XML SDK? Specially during merging multiple documents? If it is possible to merge in more documents and maintaining their original page numbers instead of continuing from where the previous page left off. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to use Section breaks, with re-starting page #s and SECTIONPAGES fields instead of NUMPAGES fields. Even without considering any page numbering issues, combining multiple Word documents requires far more than simply copying content from all the source documents and pasting it into the destination document. See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html